# ToolBar back arrow click listener is not working

Tags: android

I am facing a problem using while using  `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` my application is crashing by saying an error in logcat

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar
```

which is quite readable when i am removing the code setSupportActionbar(toolsbar) the below chucnk of code in my application is not working (This is for the back arrow in tool bar for navigating back to the previous activity.

---

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Backarrow pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try by adding this in manifest activity tag   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Comment: Try using NoActionBar theme

Comment: If that i am using toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Backarrow pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }); this part of code is not working

Comment: You can also try making a custom toolbar with a custom button and handle click events on that button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this to handle click event of  ToolBar back arrow**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Backarrow pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**add this theme to your activity**

```
 <style name="AppThemeNew" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Comment: i don't know @AbhijitChakra you can accept ans if it help you

Answer (score 0):

To use `ToolBar`, you have to set theme `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` in your `style`.

Your `style` structure be like :

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use my code its working code :

**Add in Menifest**

```
  <activity
        android:name=".DemoActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

**Activity.class**

```
  Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
        TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        mTitle.setText("Open Docket");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_back_appbar);
```

**For BackClick Event :** (put outside of `onCreate()` )

```
  @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        finish();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Backarrow pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The best solution is you have to use a Global activity that consist your toolbar layout, navigation and all control that you want to use in your whole application, then you have to just extend that activity instead of Activity like below example:

public class YourCurrentActivity extends DrawerActivity {
......
}

then you have to create application theme as per below:
<resources>
       <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>

now, you have to just set the parent activity of your current activity in manifest file  like below:

  <activity
            android:name=".YourCurrentActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ParentActivityName"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```